# Center JTextField (not the text inside the field!)

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, jtextfield

How can I center a `JTextField`.

NOTE! I do not want to center the text in the JTextField (which is achieved using `setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER)`, but rather I want to center the actual JTextField in the space it is in, just as `jLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER)` would do.

Comment: Are you using any layout? Using GridBagLayout with appropriate [GridBagConstraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#anchor) can do this. <BR>The `setHorizontalAlignment` behaves the same way for both `JTextField` and `JLabel`, both have their content aligned accordingly. You probably do not notice it in `JLabel` due to the gray colour of the background panel.

Comment: You have to use proper layout for that. Post your code if you cant get.

Comment: FlowLayout.CENTER - not sure, but something like that if you are using flowlayout

Comment: I am using null layout. There must be a way with null layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using GridBagLayout for this.

```
panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints center = new GridBagConstraints();
center.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
center.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
panel.add(textField, center);
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Null Layout:** This indicates no Layout. *Items must be manually positioned and arranged*. *This layout should only be used if the window
>   will not and cannot be resized*, as the item in the window will stay
>   where they are placed...   http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1205/java-null-layout-manager-swing/

- http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1205/java-null-layout-manager-swing/
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

The first link used `.setLocation(x, y)` to position the controls and the second link used `.setBounds(...)`. You'll need to do the centering yourself

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but never use the null layout, it's bad practice!

Comment: if you see my comment I recommended FlowLayout but the OP choose to use null layout. I don't know why this is downvoted. There is also warning in my post regarding the limitation....